# Rails - Can I use Geocoder to locate records where only the user has been geocoded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, geocoding, geocoder

A slightly frustrating issue with Geocoder.

I have two models:

```
User => has_many :records

Record => belongs_to :user
```

I'm trying to write the logic for a search function that will return all the `record` instances that are geographically close to the `current_user`.  This is along with other query params.

I understand that I can use `User.near` to get nearby users, but I can't find a straightforward way to extract the `records` that belong to those users and just return those.

Ideally, I'd like something along the lines of:

```
records = Record.where(User.near(user, 5))
```

However, I know that this won't work.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [geocoder's](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#for-activerecord-models) `nearbys` method to get all User in 5 miles range, then get all records, something like:

```
records = current_user.nearbys(5).collect(&:record)
```